# Xamarin communication with SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-services, xamarin

I'm making a project where I must have 3 platforms (ASP, Desktop (windows forms) and Xamarin) that must connect to a database. I've been experimenting but it seems I can't connect to the database directly. Sqlserver just closes the connection a few seconds later. So I tried the webservice way. I couldn't add a service reference.

I searched and it seems I had to: uninstall Xamarin.Forms nugget package in PCL, uncheck the Windows Phone in the solution properties, restart VS and reinstall the nugget package. And then I was able to add the service reference.

But then it said I needed the Sytem.Web.Services reference for it to work. But I can't add it...

So, after all this, how can I possibly connect to SQL Server like this? In ASP and Desktop it works fine, I connect directly, via a class library which contains all the connections. But I'm scratching my head about this one...

Any ideas?

Comment: How about `WebApi` layer with `CORS` enabled + `Valet Key pattern`?

Comment: All your communication with your database would ideally be through a single API. Your website, desktop app, and mobile app should all consume that API. You woudn't even necessarily need CORS. Just write a C# client for your API that you can reuse in all your consuming applications.

Comment: And how do I do that? I haven't made any webAPI's yet. I'm relatively new to programming (I think you got it already hehe). Me and my partner are working to consume one (sportsradar) but how do I make one? I mean, I already have a class library which communicates with the database, but I guess you mean another thing...

Can you give me some pointers?

I participated in the xamarin challenge and we had to use an Azure API. But I don't want have to use azure...

Comment: This has nothing to do with Azure. If you want to make an [ASP.NET Web API](https://asp.net/webapi) just read the documentation. You can consume your database class library from the API itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple applications that needs to access the same data, you're better of putting something between them that they all communicate with. This reduces the amount of duplicated logic across applications and means you only need to expose your database to a single service.

```
                        Database
                           |
                           |
                           |
                          API
                          /|\
                         / | \
                        /  |  \
                       /   |   \
                      /    |    \
            Mobile---   Desktop  ---Website
```

If you're using the .NET stack for everything, your API is probably going to be implemented in [ASP.NET Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api) or WCF. I recommend Web API, because it's simpler. Anything that can speak HTTP can talk to it.

Then, to communicate with your API, you generally create a wrapper around an low level client that makes it simple to communicate with your API's endpoints. This often takes the form of a class library wrapped around something like HttpClient or [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/). This class library is delivered via NuGet package that any .NET application can consume.

Here's some pseudo code (don't expect it to compile)

```
namespace MyClientAPI
{
    public class MyClient
    {
        private readonly string _baseAddress;

        public MyClient(string baseAddress)
        {
            _baseAddress = baseAddress;
        }

        public List<Customer> GetCustomers()
        {
            var restClient= new RestClient(_baseAddress);
            var request = new RestRequest("customers/all");
            var customers = restClient.Execute<List<Customer>>(request);
            return Customers;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, so I've been reading. I consider the official documentation to be a bit confusing. Although, I've completed [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-web-api-and-sql-server/) simple tutorial. It's simple but helps you understand the basics. Although, it doesn't tell me enough. So, now I'm going to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6n9fhu94yhW7yoUOGNOfHurUE6bpOO2b) series of youtube videos. It seems he specifies everything.

Comment: about your example, it seems to me that that is what I'll have to do later in each of my platforms to communicate to my API. Am I right? Or do I have to watch many videos? haha. Thanks, btw.

Comment: @taiko Yes, each of your applications should communicate with the Web API, via the client that you create.

Comment: I got it working, for web and desktop, at least, calling my library through the api. But in xamarin we don't have the Sytem.Web.Http, which is necessary for the Get/etc actions. With your example, about RestSharp, I see that I can only get install the nugget on the android platform. How do I do this? I've seen an example with jsonconvert.serializeobject, though...

Comment: @taiko Your API should not depend on using System.Web, which isn't very portable. That's the core of ASP.NET, and ASP.NET doesn't run everywhere. Pick something library agnostic. I don't know every library that Xamarin supports, but since that's probably the most restrictive platform you should start by finding a library that works on it, then make sure it's available on the other platforms. Put some thought into the client so you don't have to re-implement a different client for each platform. Looks like [RestSharp is available for Xamarin](https://components.xamarin.com/view/restsharp/).

Comment: Well, I spoke to a teacher where I'm taking a course and he said the easy way out is just to use the Azure's app. The harder way (to be able to do the same on any server and with my API) would be to basically do several API's. That's what he said. Don't quite understand yet what would exatly be necessary for that to happen. I'd love to, in the future, but right now I guess I'll probably just have to stick to Azure. This is for my final project and I can't waste much more time. But I'd appreciate it if you'd give me some pointers.

Comment: No, it's not harder to do what I've said. You only have to write a single client this way.

Comment: Looks like I had to get a portable version of RestSharp. So, I tried your example and it doesn't let me return the customers because it can convert. So, I try to return customers.Result.Data. But when I do it always crashes. The only message I get is "One or more errors occurred". I'm testing it on the locahost. Does it have anything to do with it?

Comment: @taiko you need to ask a new question and provide an [MCVE]. I cant tell you what's wrong without seeing the code and full error message.

Comment: Ok, I'll ask a new question. Thanks.

Comment: as I said in the other question, I finally solved it. I was doing it right. The problem was I was testing it on the localhost. So, I upped the API test app to a server and changed the link on the xamarin app and it worked. And it even works using the library on the API as intended. Thanks for the help and patience. :)